# Build a data frame dynamically

Tags: r

I have a vector of matchIds and a function that returns the players who played in that match as a vector (say getPlayersFromMatchId is the function). Now my question is, what is the most idiomatic way of iterating over the matchIds, extracting the player info and building a data frame where each row corresponds to the players who played in that match? Here's a simple for loop that does the trick

```
for (match in matchIds){
    players = getPlayersFromMatchId(match)
    Add players to a dataframe
}
```

I can iterate over the matchIds but how do I build the data frame with each value returned by the function?

Comment: You should avoid adding rows to a data.frame one-by-one. That's generally a terrible idea. Is there a reason `getPlayersFromMatchId` isn't vectorized (vector in, vector out)? You could wrap it in `Vectorize` or do a simple `sapply()` to get all the values you need at once. Your question would be much easier to answer if you actually included a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input, and desired output and code that is actually runnable.

Comment: Its extracting the data from a website depending on the matchId. I have to combine the player information for all the matches at some point.

Comment: Well your description is too vague to be precisely answered. But the general idea is fill vectors of data you want to store as columns, then combine in a data frame when done.

Comment: sapply did the trick, thanks. Sorry about the vague description.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it your way, following may help:

```
dd = data.frame(players = list())
for (match in matchIds){
    dd$players[nrow(dd)+1] = getPlayersFromMatchId(match)
    Add players to a dataframe
}
dd$players
```